# Video capture in Android 4.3 using Camera app intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-4.3-jelly-bean

How do you capture Video by calling the Android camera app using an intent in 4.3. I had it working in 4.2 and below. Even [Google's sample is broken](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html). Is this a bug? Or has Google changed how they return recorded video. Image capture still works.

I still get a RESULT_OK back but the intent data is null on MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE intents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The problem

Yes, there is a [bug starting with Android 4.3 release](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57996).

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE) says:

> If EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present the video will be written to the
>   standard location for videos, and **the Uri of that location will be
>   returned in the data field** of the Uri.

What I have experienced is that the returned data field value is `Null` instead of containing the video file's `Uri`.

---

### The solution

For now, is to pass `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` to the `Intent` specifying the output location for the video file if the device's [API Version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) is 18. This works as intended.

Since you were using the default gallery location for storing your videos, my guess is that you will want to keep it the same. So for this you need to set `EXTRA_OUTPUT` as follows.

1. Insert a new record into
   [MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Media.html#EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI):

   ```
   Uri videoUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, value);
   ```

   Being `value` a `ContentValues` with display name, file type and file path to the new video file. E.g. :

   ```
   ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
   value.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "VideoTitle");
   value.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
   value.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, videoFilePath);
   ```
2. Pass the returned value, `videoUri`, as the `EXTRA_OUPUT` to the `Intent`.